# Does the part of the sentence that comes after "support"- to enable then ... - refers to "support" or it refers to the whole sentence?

Tags: ambiguity

This chapter also discusses the role of the refuge workers, the approach they took to their work and their needs for support to enable then to work effectively with women in a stressed and pressurized environment.

Comment: I don't think the sentence-modifier reading makes sense ('[discussing] the approach they **took** to their work' doesn't seem all that connected to 'enabl[ing] the[m] to work effectively with women' though I suppose one learns from one's mistakes), but this _is_ inherently ambiguous. So 'support geared towards enabling ...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers only to *support*. The sentence wouldn't make sense otherwise, i.e., it wouldn't make sense if "to enable them …" also modified "the role of refuge workers" and "the approach they took to their work".

I might reword the sentence as follows: "This chapter also discusses the role of the refuge workers, the approach they took (take?) to their work and the support they need (needed?) to work effectively with women in a stressed and pressurized environment."